# How to display an output in awk by providing a dynamic variable and checking them in a text file

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/user/bin/bash
a=$1
echo $1
awk '$1=="$a"{print $2}' Test.txt
```

> I am trying to assign a value to $a dynamically and check that value in text file using awk. if $1 is equal to $a then it should display $2 in the text file.

---

A   HIGH

B   LOW

C   MEDIUM

D   HELLO

E   Hai

---

> I tried passing $a hardcoded in awk and it worked and provided me the expected output but I am not able to pass a variable in that place

---

```
#!/user/bin/bash
a=$1
echo $1
awk '/A/ {print $2}' Test.txt
```

---

> I am looking for a way to pass a value to $a dynamically while running the shell script

Comment: I came up with this script to get my output.
`#!/bin/bash`
`a=$1`
var=`grep $1 Test.txt | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to awk like this:

```
awk -v var=$1 '{print var}'
```

Pri.txt:

```
A High
B Low
C Medium
```

display.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v a=$1 '$1 == a {print $2}' Pri.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ./display.sh A
High
```

Comment: I tried the following but still It is not working

`awk -v ses=$1 '{if(ses==$1)
print $2
}' Test.txt`

Comment: What's inside the variable $1?  What about the Test.txt file?

Comment: $1 value changes dynamically. It gets it's input manually while I run the script and Test.txt has two coulmns. I have to match the $1 value that i get manually in the Test.txt and display the respective column

Comment: I mean specifically in your example where you said "I tried the following".  What was the specific value of $1 here?  What about Test.txt?

Comment: I passed a string as an input for $1

Comment: What string?? Help me to help you, please.  What was the string? What are the contents of Test.txt?

Comment: So I passed $1 = A. And in my text file, I will have A High,B Low, C Medium. If I pass A, it must display High.
Below is the script I eneded up doing for the above mentioned problem.
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
var=`grep $1 Pri.txt | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $var

Comment: I've edited my answer - let me know if this clears things up.